# Should i declare model class properties in phalcon when using Phalcon\Mvc\Model::columnMap()?

Tags: php, model, phalcon

Usually we need to define public properties in model class, that represent table columns. As was said in docs and on development forums defining such public properties increases perfomance.

But if we use column mapping as described here:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#independent-column-mapping

Should we declate public properties? If yes, what properties should be defined? Column names from database or their mapping names in application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define properties on classes is a good practice because it reduces the overall memory consumption (this only applies for PHP >= 5.4.x). So you must define properties for all classes when possible not only models.

This is an advanced explanation of why it reduces this increases performance: https://gist.github.com/nikic/5015323

Comment: So i should define public properties in my model class as model columns in application, or as model columns in database?

Comment: As model columns in application